# Extracting the HTML colour code for each node of a Kohonen plot

Tags: r, som

I am using the following script to plot a SOM and I would like to extract the HTML colour code corresponding to each node.

It doesn't seem to be in the som_model s3 object.

Any idea?

```
library(kohonen)

data<-matrix(c(-0.406,-0.406,-0.406,-0.406,2.463,-0.406,-0.406,2.463,-0.406,-0.406,-0.406,-0.406,
  -0.406,-0.406,-0.406,-0.406,-0.406,-0.406,-0.406,-0.406,0.4188448,1.6027146,0.7208751,
  0.7724322,0.5655424,-1.6969826,0.3429044,0.396769,0.3224141,-0.7324542,-0.5303228,0.9943725,
  -0.0324817,1.321637,-1.1985506,-0.3409802,-0.1393889,-0.3964047,0.9597519,-0.2443682), ncol=2)    

som_grid <- somgrid(xdim = 4, ydim=4, topo="hexagonal")

som_model <- som(data, 
                 grid=som_grid, 
                 rlen=100, 
                 alpha=c(0.05,0.01), 
                 keep.data = TRUE,
                 n.hood='circular')

plot(som_model,type="count")
```

The output I am looking for would be a list/vector with the colour code for each node:
"#0000FF",  "#FF0000"...

Answer (score 0):

The `plot` call is really a call to `plot.kohonen` and that, in turn, calls `plot.kohprop` to setup some plot aesthetics, including the color scheme . The default color scheme is `heat.colors` + `gray`. For your case, you can do `heat.colors(3)` and then look at `som_model$grid` to determine the color mapping.

You can see what `plot.kohprop` does by just entering the function name sans parens at an R console.